# HTML5 Video - Playing low fps video

Tags: html, video, frame-rate, live-streaming

I'm live streaming low fps video to a webpage and using the html5 video element. The problem that I'm facing is that the load time for low fps (1fps) video is about 50 seconds. When I stream at 24fps there is very little loading time. I have checked and my 1fps stream is coming through a long time before the video is actually displayed - And once the video starts, I can speed up the video and catch up to the live timestamp. What is going on here? Does the video element need a certain amount of frames before it will start playing? What can I do to get my 1fps video to show in the player as soon as the stream becomes ready?

The code that I'm using in the html is as follows...

```
<video src="localhost:44375/GetVideoAsync"; type="video/webm" 
autoplay="autoplay"></video>
```

GetVideoAsync is a call to a .Net api that returns a live video stream.

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public async Task<Stream> GetVideoAsync() {
  return await _streamingService.GetVideoAsync();
}
```

So - the source of the video is really not that important - the issue is getting low fps video (1fps) to start playing sooner - or just as quick as 24fps video

Comment: Your question is quite broad - can you provide more specific details about the html code that does the downloading, and the source of the video stream. (See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks.

Comment: Updated the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few hard-set buffers along the way which are not optimized for low bitrate video.  These are effectively bugs, but nothing you can really do about them besides report the issues.

Comment: What I'm thinking of doing  is prepending my stream with 48 frames at a higher frame rate - to "initialize"  the stream. I kind of did a proof of concept by switching from fast to low frame rates mid stream.A bit of a hack...but as you mentioned - it is effectively a bug - so will have to find a workaround. Thanks.